# Creating strings and adding them to a linked list, but they are blank when printed

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am trying to read text from a file, with the following format : ID,username,Text

When I try to store to the node character by character, the string is blank. See the comments (HELP**)
Here is my Code:

```
        while(fgets(contents, 250, fp) != NULL)                 // take one line of data, and copy it to contents until EOF is reached
    {
        i = 0;

        post = malloc(sizeof(message));                       // allocates dynamic memory for the node struct

        while(contents[i] != ',')                           //copies id digits to a string of digits
        {
            id[i] = contents[i];
            ++i;
        }

        id[i] = '\0';                                       // insert null character at end of string
        ++i;

        while(contents[i] != ',')                          //copies username to node user entry
        {
            post->user[i] = contents[i];
            ++i;
        }
        
        post->user[i] = '\0';                               // insert null character at end of string
        //HELP** PRINTING POST->USER PRINTS BLANK
        ++i;

        while(contents[i] != '\n')                          //copies post text to node user entry
        {
            post->text[i] = contents[i];
            ++i;
        }
       
        post->text[i] = '\0';                               // insert null character at end of string
        //HELP** PRINTING POST->TEXT PRINTS BLANK

        if(post->text[strlen(post->text)] == ',')           // if there is a comma at the end of the post, remove it
        {
            post->text[strlen(post->text)] = '\0';
        }

        post->id = atoi(id);                                // convert string of ID to an integer and set it to the nodes ID

        addNodeToList(headmessage, post);                     //adds the node created to the linked list 
    }
}
```

Here is the struct for the node in the linked list :

```
typedef struct message
{
int id;                 //unique integer value  
char user[50];          // the username
char text[120];         // the text of the message

struct message *next;  //dynamic connection to the next tweet
}message;
```

With text file :

```
37,userf,hello
96,userd,hello
36,userc,hello
37,userb,hello
123,usera,hello
```

When printing Linked list after loop above:

```
37: <username supposed to be here>:<text supposed to be here>
96: :
36: :
37: :
123: :
```

It appears the ID does work, but the strings do not work. If I add a debug line to print each character as it stores, it appears to get the correct characters, but once the loop finishes the printing the string prints blank

Comment: `post->user[i] = contents[i];` Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. What is the value of `i` at that point? And is it right to use that value as an array index for  the `user` field?

Comment: @kaylum if I print i at those points, they point to the correct index in the text file. if I print the character at that point, it spells out the usernames correctly. the strings in the linked list just print blank.

Comment: Yes but is it correct to use that same index for the `user` field? You want to start copying  into `user` from index `0`. Not in the middle of the `user` array which is what you are doing by using `i`.

Comment: @kaylum Oh my god you are correct. Im going to try to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you found the issue.

But, using `strtok` can simplify the code:

```
// take one line of data, and copy it to contents until EOF is reached
while (fgets(contents, 250, fp) != NULL)
{

    // allocates dynamic memory for the node struct
    post = malloc(sizeof(message));

    char *tok;

    // copies id digits to a string of digits
    tok = strtok(contents,",");
    post->id = atoi(tok);

    // copies username to node user entry
    tok = strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(post->user,tok);

    // HELP** PRINTING POST->USER PRINTS BLANK

    // copies post text to node user entry
    tok = strtok(NULL,",\n");
    strcpy(post->text,tok);

    // adds the node created to the linked list
    addNodeToList(headmessage, post);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@kaylum Solved the Problem, It was because I used [i] as the index for the node arrays.

It was solved by creating another index number (j) to store to the correct index in the node

Comment: Good to hear you found your solution! Please consider accepting your own answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

at this point in the posted code:

```
post->user[i] = contents[i];
```

The variable `i` is already far past the end of the `user` field.

I.E.  before entering that loop that reads the `user` info, need a statement like: `int j = 0;`  then

```
post->user[j] = contents[i];
```